microsoft.identitymode.tokens.audienceurivalidationfailedexception was thrown while trying to open One Drive document in WKWebView in iOS app
I am working in iOS app needs to be opened One Drive attachments in WKWebView.
Sample One Drive document is
https://\*\*\*.sharepoint.com/personal/\*\*\*\*\*\_onmicrosoft_com/\_layouts/15/Doc.aspx?sourcedoc=%7B756B3139-9729-49D2-A325-9D3B150C6A78%7D&file=export.csv&action=default&mobileredirect=true

I got the this error
"microsoft.identitymode.tokens.audienceurivalidationfailedexception was thrown" inside the loaded WKWebView
Please suggest me to fix the issue.
Thanks in Advance
To load the document in the WKWebView, here is the code snippet:
WKWebViewConfiguration *configuration = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
    if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:[TMEUserDefaultKeys cdnSetCookie]]) {
        WKUserContentController *userContentController = WKUserContentController.new;
        WKUserScript *cookieScript = [[WKUserScript alloc]
              initWithSource:[NSString
                                 stringWithFormat:@"document.cookie = '%@';",
                                                  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:[TMEUserDefaultKeys cdnSetCookie]]]
               injectionTime:WKUserScriptInjectionTimeAtDocumentStart
            forMainFrameOnly:NO];
        [userContentController addUserScript:cookieScript];
        [configuration setUserContentController:userContentController];
    }
    WKPreferences *preferences = [[WKPreferences alloc] init];
    preferences.javaScriptEnabled = YES;
    configuration.preferences = preferences;
    configuration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES;
    configuration.allowsPictureInPictureMediaPlayback = YES;
    configuration.mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback = WKAudiovisualMediaTypeAll;
    NSArray<NSHTTPCookie *> *cookies = [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies];
    for(NSHTTPCookie *cookie in cookies) {
        [configuration.websiteDataStore.httpCookieStore setCookie:cookie completionHandler:nil];
    }

    self.webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds configuration:configuration];
    self.webView.UIDelegate = self;
    self.webView.navigationDelegate = self;
    self.webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    self.webView.scrollView.bounces = NO;
    self.webView.scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    self.webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:self.webView];
    
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:self.documentURL
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                       timeoutInterval:60.0];

    [request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@", self.oneDriveToken] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
    [request addValue:@"https://***.sharepoint.com/.default" forHTTPHeaderField:@"scope"];
    [self.webView loadRequest:request];

